# $ABA$ is nilpotent, then is $BAB$ nilpotent too?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know about the problem which asks

> If $AB$ is nilpotent, then so is $BA$. This statement is true and the proof is simple.

Now I want to know if

> $ABA$ is nilpotent, then is $BAB$ nilpotent too?

I could not prove it. I tried disproving it by looking for some counter-example but that did not work either. I went through some elementary matrices but that did not help at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: right, I eventually ended up with this idea. A simple example for $A$ would be $E_{12}$

Answer (score 6):

Take

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 1 \\
     0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 1 \\
     1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $A=E_{12}$
$$(ABA)^2=AB(A)^2BA=AB0BA$$

On the other hand $BAB=B$ and $B$ is not nilpotent